# What are the eigenvalues of the following symmetric matrix?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

> Given matrix $$M=\begin{bmatrix}0&1&2&0\\ 1&0&1&0\\2&1&0&2\\0&0&2&0\end{bmatrix}$$
>    Then,
>
> 1. $M$ has no real eigenvalues.
> 2. all real eigenvalues of $M$ are positive.
> 3. all real eigenvalues of $M$ are negative.
> 4. $M$ has both positive and negative real eigenvalues.

So I calculated the characteristic polynomial of $M$ and found it to be $x^4-10x^2-4x+4=0$. I tried using rational root theorem to determine its roots but could not find any. So this means that ooption 1 is correct. But on the other hand every real symmetric matrix has real eigenvalues. So isn't it a absurd conclusion.

Comment: Computing the values of the characteristic polynomial at $x=-1$, $x=0$, $x=+1$, shows that 4. and only 4. holds.

Comment: $p(0)=4, p(1)=-9,p(-1)=-1$ So there are positive and negative real eigenvalues.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First note that as $M$ is symmetric so all our eigenvalues are real. Now we know that $tr(M)=\sum_i \lambda_i $ and $det(M)=\prod_i \lambda_i$. And we have $det(M)=4$ which implies that none of the eigenvalue is zero and combining this with $tr(M)=0$ tells us that option 4 is correct.

Comment: Since $M$ is symmetric (all eigenvalues are real), non-zero (not all eigenvalues are zero), and traceless (but the sum of the eigenvalues is zero), there is no need to also compute the determinant to reach the same conclusion.

Comment: Actually this answer is wrong since it does not use the symmetry of M which is crucial to conclude with this approach.

Answer (score 2):

The rational root theorem giving no roots for $\chi_M$ does only say that $M$ does not have **rational** eigenvalues. To determine the signs of the real(! - $M$ is symmetric, hence all its eigenvalues are real) eigenvalues, compute $\chi_M(0)$, $\chi_M(-1)$ and $\chi_M(1)$. We have
$$ \chi_M(\pm 1) < 0, \chi_M(0) > 0 $$
So $\chi_M$ has roots in $(0,1)$ and in $(-1,0)$. So 4. is true.